# How to set datasets with different tooltip mode in ChartJs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, chart.js, tooltip

I'm having a mixed chart with Bar and Line charts. I want to set the tooltip mode for Bar chart datasets to 'index' and Line chart datasets to 'point'. I've tried to set mode like the below ways, but any of them didn't work. It only considers the mode set inside 'Options'.

1. Set mode via dataset

   ```
   [{
      data : [<DATA>],
      id : '<ID>',
      label: 'Line chart'                  
      type: 'line',
      radius: 5,
      showLine: false,
      pointRadius: 3,
      mode: 'point' 
   },
   {
      data : [<DATA>],
      id : '<ID>',
      label: 'Bar chart'                  
      type: 'bar',
      radius: 5,
      showLine: false,
      pointRadius: 3,
      mode: 'index'
   }]
   ```
2. Set mode via scriptable options